# How to return only the value of the last month

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a dashboard where in my data I have a column called "Data Base", because it is a column where it has dates of all the days that I update, and in my dashboard it shows by the months, either "January, February, March , etc..." and I need it to pull the amount from the book balance by the last day of each month. How to do this?

Column Data Base:

[image: Column Data Base]

Dashboard:

[image: Dashboard]

OBS it is accumulating everything, so a huge and wrong number is coming in this case, I need you to pull the accounting value for the last day of each of these months.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a calculated column to your table to calculate if each row represents the end of a month, then use that as filter (Page or Visual).

I usually prefer Power Query for calculated columns, but this might be easier in a DAX column, e.g.

```
Is End of Month ? = IF ( [Data Base] = EOMONTH ( [Data Base], 0 ), "End of Month" )
```

Then in the Report pane I would add that new column as a filter, either at the Page or Visual level, as appropriate.